# Create SP site collection when create new TFS collection with service account added temporarily

Tags: tfs

I need to create a new team project collection in TFS 2015 Update 3 and I am following [Create a Team Project Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/manage-team-project-collections#create-a-team-project-collection)

This question is related to SharePoint Site collection only (created during TFS collection creation)

TFS service account is not presently member of the Farm Administrators group on SharePoint 2010 but intend on allowing temporarily during creation new TFS 2015 team project collection in TFS (which will create new SharePoint site collection as well) and then remove after collection creation.

Will this create proper permissions to the SharePoint site collection?

Comment: added some whitespace so the question is easier to digest

Comment: What permission do you need? You can use an existing site collection that a member of the Farm Administrators group created for you when create TFS team project collection.

Comment: Hi Cece, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies-tfs#service-accounts-for-team-foundation-server the TFS Service should be member of SP Farm Admin . So in this case TFS service should have privilege to create the site collection. I believe this should be the answer. Please let me know if agreed.

Comment: @drhorg Yes, creating a site collection requires the TFS service account to be a member of the Farm Administrators group.Or, to use an existing site collection that a member of the Farm Administrators group created for you.